# fb:comments - What exactly is going to be dropped on 1 Jan 2012?

Tags: comments, fbml, xfbml

Is facebook going to completely remove xid attribute, replacing it with href only? I hope not, because xid is a lot more flexible than href. Is facebook going to drop all <fb:... > tags? Or are these tags going to work after 1 Jan 2012, but we will call it XFBML, not FBML? Is an official statement somewhere available?

I am getting pretty desperate after spending many hours trying to sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer to your question is [yes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments/). From the link:

> **We are deprecating FBML.** On **Jan 1, 2012:** FBML will no longer be supported on Platform. **June 1, 2012:** FBML apps will no longer work. All FBML endpoints are removed. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

I'm not a Facebook developer, so it's hard to say what you would migrate to in the JavaScript SDK/Social Plugin realm.

Comment: Unfortunately, I share your opinion, so I've just migrated to HTML5 implementation and to href attribute. Hope that the migration makes me safe for a few years. The bad news is that I've lost my previous comments.

Comment: If you think this is the right answer, click the green check-mark outline next to it to accept it. That way, anyone else who's looking for answers to this question will find it.